# Transparent header in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently doing some editing on this website: http://www.katiemalinmakeupartist.com

I want to have a completely transparent header. I have made this custom CSS:

```
#header {
background: transparent !important;
background-position: top center !important;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2) !important;
}

#logo {
display:none;
}

#mobile-logo {
display:none;
}

#mobile-header.mobile-header.v1 {
background: transparent !important;
}
```

Transparency does not work on any device. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you have used background color in this

## header.header-v1 {background: #ffffff;}

Maybe that's why it won't work.